# Class Naus\bundle\Entity\Sample is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

i made a new bundle,
made a new controller
made few entities

entity does get in the database when i use php console dotrine:schema:update --force

i make a form,
form pops great,
when i submit i use

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($type);
                $em->flush();


                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_success'));
            }
```

i get a big fat error :

> Class Naus\Biobalance\Entity\Sample is not a valid entity or mapped
>   super class.

i've double checked my top..
and use Naus\bundle\Entity\Sample; is mentioned like it is supposed to be ?
no clear answers online, hope someone can help..

the first lines of the entity (on request)

```
<?php 

namespace Naus\Biobalance\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample")
 */
class Sample
{
```

regarding the appkernel :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),

            new Knplabs\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnplabsMenuBundle(),
            new Knplabs\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnplabsSnappyBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new AntiMattr\GoogleBundle\GoogleBundle(),
            new Fp\OpenIdBundle\FpOpenIdBundle(),

            new Naus\Api\NausApi(),
            new Naus\App\NausApp(),
            new Naus\Cms\NausCms(),
            new Naus\Crm\NausCrm(),
            new Naus\Event\NausEvent(),
            new Naus\Form\NausForm(),
            new Naus\Invoicing\NausInvoicing(),
            new Naus\Mail\NausMail(),
            new Naus\Media\NausMedia(),
            new Naus\Member\NausMember(),
            new Naus\Meta\NausMeta(),
            new Naus\Project\NausProject(),
            new Naus\Vacancy\NausVacancy(),
            new Naus\Workgroup\NausWorkgroup(),
            new Naus\Biobalance\NausBiobalance(),
```

Comment: Please post the first few lines of the entity code (down to the construct line).  Confirm the console sees it with: php console doctrine:mapping:info

Comment: <?php 

namespace Naus\Biobalance\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="component_site")
 */
class Site

Comment: first time on stackoverflow, sorry guys..

Comment: no problem, welcome to SO and +1 for your question

Comment: I think the Entity you were asked for was the Sample entity, not the Site entity.

Comment: updated the code in the initial post

Comment: Now what about the CLI? Does the `doctrine:mapping:info` show your entity?

Comment: great advice, it does not show up when i do the doctrine:mapping:info

Comment: I would have expected Biobalance to be BiobalanceBundle?  Can you post the relevant lines from AppKernel showing where you register your bundle?

Comment: just added the appkernel lines (it's the last line for the biobalance

Comment: i guess the bundle wasn't registered somewhere right.. if it doesn't show up in the mapping:info , could i add it in some way or refresh that mapping ?

Comment: Way too many bundles! But that is probably not the problem but I would suggest you chop all the bundles out except for Biobalance until you get the console command to work.  In you question you have: 'Naus\bundle\Entity\Sample'.  Is 'bundle' a copy/paste error?

Comment: bundle is a copy paste error, .. the bundles well it's quite a big framework.. the lead moved to freelance and isn't reachable, and i have a deliverable tomorrow :/

Comment: I think there is an `auto_mapping` setting in the config.yml. Is it set to true?

Comment: it was on false, changed it... now i an error for an entity that doesn't exists any more, guess that's why it was placed on false..

Comment: Look into the other bundles. How do they make the mapping? search the web for auto_mapping, I think you'll find things about how to do the mapping manually

Comment: it's solved, the automapping did the trick and is a good solid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, setting the auto_mapping setting found in config.yml solves the problem.

Comment: You sir, are a legend! I've been looking for the solution to a similar problem for the past 4 hours solid and you've just fixed it for me. Thanks!